# I keep Getting The Error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

It says Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

(my code)

```
func getData()  {

   let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try? context.fetch(request)

        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {

            FacialViewControllerA = data.value(forKey: "titleA") as! String


    }
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: your result is nil and you are trying to force wrap to [NSManagedObject]. That's why this error is coming.

Comment: can u help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood what the `do-try-catch` block does.

When you put the `?` after `try` you are preventing the catch from getting hit. So if `try` fails, it is setting `result` to `nil`. Then you are force casting `nil` to `[NSManagedObject]`.

You have two options:

- Remove the `?` after `try`
- Like Vikram mentioned, don't force cast result, use `as? [NSManagedObject]`

1)

```
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request)
    for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
        FacialViewControllerA = data.value(forKey: "titleA") as! String
    }
} catch {
    print("There was an error: \(error)")
}
```

2)

```
if let result = try? context.fetch(request) as? [NSManagedObject] {
    for data in result  {
        FacialViewControllerA = data.value(forKey: "titleA") as! String
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but when i remove (try) it gives me the error: "Errors thrown from here are not handled"

Comment: @MyzXI you have to add the `catch` part of the block. I've updated my answer with code examples

Comment: thank you, works like a charm :)

Comment: @MyzXI glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to Tyler's comment so you learn more about optionals. Also, avoid the usage of `!` which is used to force unwrap objects.

In your case, the crash could be happening due to two reasons:

- Either the object you are trying to unwrap is not an array `[NSManagedObject]`
- Or the fetchRequest returned `0` objects or `nil` value

To avoid the crash you should opt for optional unwrapping which is the safest way of unwrapping an object. You can either a `guard-let` or `If-let` statement
 Please refer to the code below:

Using guard-let:

```
guard let unwrappedResult = result as? [NSManagedObject] else {
        print("unwrap of result failed")
        return
 }
 for data in unwrappedResult {
     //perform your logic
 }
```

Using if-let:

```
if let unwrappedResult = result as? [NSManagedObject] {
   for data in unwrappedResult {
       //perform your logic
   }
}
```

Comment: That code would not work either, since result would be optional. You should add `?? []` to the end.

Comment: @Wyetro Thanks for the highlight. I have updated my approach anyways :)

Comment: Looks good! This would definitely be a way to solve the issue